# Jest mock inner function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have one file called **helper.js** that consist of two functions

```
export const funcA = (key) => {
   return funcB(key)
};

export const funcB = (key,prop) => {
   return someObj;
};
```

I have my **helper.spec.js** to test the helper.js file functions.

```
import {funcA,funcB} from 'helper';

describe('helper', () => {
   test('testFuncB', () => {

   }
   test('testFuncA', () => {

   }
}
```

The test for funcB is pretty simple i just call it and expect **someObj**
The problem is to test funcA, in order to test it i want to mock the response of funcB.

I want **testFuncB** call the actual **funcB** and **testFuncA** call mocked **funcB**

How can i achieve funcB to be mocked and original in my two tests?

This is not a duplicate. It is a different case: they mock inner called functions only, if I remove the testFuncB then it will be the same but I must perform test on testFuncB too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942866/mocking-a-function-call-inside-a-function-in-jest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a function call inside a function in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942866/mocking-a-function-call-inside-a-function-in-jest)

Comment: The answer is only part of my question. updated the question.

Comment: you can try to mock *funcB* only _inside_ the *testFuncA*.

Comment: How do i do it? do you have a code example?

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik I just stumbled on this old question because someone had linked to it.  The accepted answer doesn't work.  I've added a new answer with an explanation and working example.  Please consider making it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

If an ES6 module directly exports two functions (not within a class, object, etc., just directly exports the functions like in the question) and one directly calls the other, then **that call cannot be mocked**.

In this case, `funcB` **cannot be mocked** within `funcA` the way the code is currently written.

A mock replaces the **module export** for `funcB`, but `funcA` doesn't call the **module export** for `funcB`, it just calls `funcB` directly.

---

Mocking `funcB` within `funcA` requires that `funcA` call the **module export** for `funcB`.

That can be done in one of two ways:

---

**Move `funcB` to its own module**

funcB.js

```js
export const funcB = () => {
  return 'original';
};
```

helper.js

```js
import { funcB } from './funcB';

export const funcA = () => {
  return funcB();
};
```

helper.spec.js

```js
import * as funcBModule from './funcB';
import { funcA } from './helper';

describe('helper', () => {

  test('test funcB', () => {
    expect(funcBModule.funcB()).toBe('original');  // Success!
  });

  test('test funcA', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(funcBModule, 'funcB');
    spy.mockReturnValue('mocked');

    expect(funcA()).toBe('mocked');  // Success!

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

---

**Import the module into itself**

["ES6 modules support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_cyclic-dependencies) so it is perfectly valid to `import` a module into itself so that functions within the module can call the **module export** for other functions in the module:

helper.js

```js
import * as helper from './helper';

export const funcA = () => {
  return helper.funcB();
};

export const funcB = () => {
  return 'original';
};
```

helper.spec.js

```js
import * as helper from './helper';

describe('helper', () => {

  test('test funcB', () => {
    expect(helper.funcB()).toBe('original');  // Success!
  });

  test('test funcA', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(helper, 'funcB');
    spy.mockReturnValue('mocked');

    expect(helper.funcA()).toBe('mocked');  // Success!

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: What to do when I get `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import `?

Comment: @Prakhar you'll need to [compile with something like Babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) since ES6 module support in Node.js [is still just experimental](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules)

Comment: @Prakhar in the above example use `exports.funcB(key)` inside the `funcA`

Comment: @BrianAdams how do i spy only 1 particular function that is nested; through the second approach?   for example:  funcA calls {funcB, funcC, funcD,} and funcC in turn calls {funcCC} which in turn calls {funcCCC}, i want to write test for funcA by mocking just funcCCC

Comment: @Ganga `funcCCC` just needs to be exported and `funcCC` needs to call it by using the module.  If `funcCC` calls `funcCCC` using the module then the module export for `funcCCC` can be mocked during the test.

Comment: When I run the first example I get `TypeError: (0 , _helper.funcA) is not a function`

Comment: You mentioned "not within a class, object". Does that mean things are different if the functions are within a class or object?

Answer (score 7):

Late answer but this should work.
Also you should test funcB in its own file and not inside the 'helper' tests.

```
import { funcB } from './funcB';
import { funcA } from './helper';

jest.mock('./funcB');

describe('helper', () => {
    test('test funcA', () => {
        const funcBSpy = jest.fn();
        funcB.mockImplementation(() => funcBSpy());
        
        funcA();

        expect(funcBSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I create a kind of nameSpace to handle this issue:

```
let helper = {}

const funcA = (key) => {
   return helper.funcB(key)
};

const funcB = (key,prop) => {
    return someObj;
};

helper = { funcA, funcB }

module.exports = helper
```

and then mocking is obvious with `jest.fn`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) provided `__set__` function to mock internal function.

Assuming you have set up babel-plugin-rewire.

helper.spec.js

```js
import {funcA, __set__} as helper from './helper';

describe('helper', () => {
  test('test funcA', () => {
    __set__('funcB', () => {
      return 'funcB return value'
    })

    expect(funcA()).toBe('funcB return value'); 
  });
});
```

One advantage of this solution is you don't need to change any original code

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as helper from 'helper';

    describe('helper', () => {
       it('should test testFuncA', () => {
          const mockTestFuncB = jest.mock();
          // spy on calls to testFuncB and respond with a mock function

           mockTestFuncB.spyOn(helper, 'testFuncB').mockReturnValue(/*your expected return value*/);

          // test logic

          // Restore helper.testFuncB to it's original function
          helper.testFuncB.mockRestore();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. I separated my helper and my main logic into two files like other solutions. In the test file, I had to mock the entire helper file.

```
const { doAdd } = require('./addHelper');

function add(a, b) {
  return doAdd(a, b);
}
```

```
jest.mock('./addHelper');

// ...

it('should call doAdd', () => {
  // hook into doAdd helper method and intercept its return value
  jest.spyOn(helperModule, 'doAdd').mockReturnValue(11);

  expect(addModule.add()).toEqual(11);
  expect(helperModule.doAdd).toBeCalled();
});
```

Here is my solution:

https://github.com/davidholyko/jest-sandbox

Comment: This worked well for me using Next.js

Answer (score -1):

I think this might work

```
import * as helper from 'helper';

describe('helper', () => {
   test('testFuncB', () => {

   }
   test('testFuncA', () => {
      const mockTestFuncB = jest.mock();
      // spy on calls to testFuncB and respond with a mock function
      jest.spyOn(helper, 'testFuncB').mockImplementationOnce(mockTestFuncB);

      // Do the testing ...

      // Restore helper.testFuncB to it's original function
      helper.testFuncB.mockRestore();
   }
}
```

Comment: Note for new viewers of this question: this doesn't work.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193363/10149510) for an explanation and working example.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following trick when you test the `funcA`:

1.Mock the `funcB`:

```
helper.funcB = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => <your data>);
```

2.Change the `funcB(key)` to `this.funcB(key)`

I had the same problem and worked! Full Code:

```
export const funcA = (key) => {
    return this.funcB(key)
};

export const funcB = (key,prop) => {
    return someObj;
};
```

Test Code:

```
import helper from 'helper';

describe('helper', () => {
   test('testFuncB', () => {
       ...
   }
   test('testFuncA', () => {
       helper.funcB = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => <your data>);
   }
}
```