# How to mock a function in Jest

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I have the following typescript class which I want to test in Jest.

```
//MyClass.ts
import { foo } from './somewhere/FooFactory';
export class MyClass {
  private _state : number;
  constructor( arg : string ) {
    this._state = foo( arg );
  }

  public getState() : string {
    return this._state;
  }
}
```

This is my test:

```
//MyClass.spec.ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';
describe( 'test MyClass', () => {
  test( 'construct' => {
    const c = new MyClass( 'test' );
    expect( c ).toBeDefined();
    expect( c.getState() ).toEqual( 'TEST' );
  } );
} );
```

How do I mock the foo function used inside MyClass so that this test passes?

Comment: looks like the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are a few different ways to approach it.

---

You can mock only `foo` using [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) and something like [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

```ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';
import * as FooFactory from './somewhere/FooFactory';

describe('test MyClass', () => {
  test('construct', () => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(FooFactory, 'foo');  // spy on foo
    mock.mockImplementation((arg: string) => 'TEST');  // replace implementation

    const c = new MyClass('test');
    expect(c).toBeDefined();
    expect(c.getState()).toEqual('TEST');  // SUCCESS

    mock.mockRestore();  // restore original implementation
  });
});
```

---

Similarly, you can auto-mock `FooFactory` with [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), then provide an implementation for `foo`:

```ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';
import * as FooFactory from './somewhere/FooFactory';

jest.mock('./somewhere/FooFactory');  // auto-mock FooFactory

describe('test MyClass', () => {
  test('construct', () => {
    const mockFooFactory = FooFactory as jest.Mocked<typeof FooFactory>;  // get correct type for mocked FooFactory
    mockFooFactory.foo.mockImplementation(() => 'TEST');  // provide implementation for foo

    const c = new MyClass('test');
    expect(c).toBeDefined();
    expect(c.getState()).toEqual('TEST');  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

---

You can also mock `FooFactory` using a module factory passed to [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

```ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

jest.mock('./somewhere/FooFactory', () => ({
  foo: () => 'TEST'
}));

describe('test MyClass', () => {
  test('construct', () => {
    const c = new MyClass('test');
    expect(c).toBeDefined();
    expect(c.getState()).toEqual('TEST');  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

---

And finally, if you plan to use the same mock across multiple test files you can [mock the user module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) by creating a mock at `./somewhere/__mocks__/FooFactory.ts`:

```ts
export function foo(arg: string) {
  return 'TEST';
}
```

...then call `jest.mock('./somewhere/FooFactory');` to use the mock in the test:

```ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

jest.mock('./somewhere/FooFactory');  // use the mock

describe('test MyClass', () => {
  test('construct', () => {
    const c = new MyClass('test');
    expect(c).toBeDefined();
    expect(c.getState()).toEqual('TEST');  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: I logged into stackoverflow just to upvote this answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: This was so helpful!

Comment: How about when `MyClass` and `foo` are inside the same module?

Comment: @EmreTapcı see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193363/10149510 (TLDR: import the module into itself and reference `foo` within `MyClass` using the module, then you can mock `foo` using the module)

Comment: @BrianAdams that is, without having to modify the source code.

Comment: @EmreTapcı mocking relies on a level of indirection so if `MyClass` and `foo` are in the same module and `MyClass` calls `foo` directly then there isn't any indirection and that call to `foo` can't be mocked without first modifying the source code.  (basically there isn't a place for a mock to squeeze in and redirect the call to something else)