# Jest mock function inside function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

I have no idea how to mock return value of inner function inside jest
I tried different approaches. Finally I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function)
but value not mocking for some reason, here it is example:

countries.js

```js
export const countryList = () => [
      {
        label: '+244',
        value: 'Angola',
      }, // list of all possible countries very long...
 ];

export const getSortedCountryData = intlLang =>
  countriesList()
  .sort((compare, comparable) =>
    compare.value.localeCompare(comparable.value, intlLang, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
```

countries.test.js

```js
import * as countyListHelper from './countries';

describe('countries list', () => {
  test('returns list of countries', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.mock();

    const expectedList = [
      {
        label: '+244',
        value: 'Angola',
      },
      {
        label: '+43',
        value: 'Austria',
      },
    ];

    mockFn.spyOn(countyListHelper, 'countriesList').mockReturnValue(expectedList);

    // console.log('if return value mocked correctly',
    // countyListHelper.countriesList() === expectedList); // true
    expect(countyListHelper.getSortedCountryData('en')).toEqual(expectedList);
    // shows error with received value list of all countries instead of mocked one
  });
});
```

Please suggest me any possible solutions why inside test function mocked return value for inner function is ignored. Setup from Create React App.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The question you linked to has a currently accepted answer that doesn't work.  I added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193363/10149510) with an explanation and working example.

The same concept applies here: a mock replaces the **module export** of a function so to be able to mock `countriesList` within `getSortedCountryData` you have to call the **module export** for `countriesList`.

One option is to move `countriesList` to its own module.

The other option is to take advantage of the fact that ["ES6 modules support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_cyclic-dependencies) so it is perfectly valid to `import` the module into itself so that you can call the **module export** for `countriesList`:

countries.js

```js
import * as countyListHelper from './countries';

export const countriesList = () => [
  {
    label: '+244',
    value: 'Angola',
  }, // list of all possible countries very long...
];

export const getSortedCountryData = intlLang =>
  countyListHelper.countriesList()
    .sort((compare, comparable) =>
      compare.value.localeCompare(comparable.value, intlLang, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
```

countries.test.js

```js
import * as countyListHelper from './countries';

describe('countries list', () => {
  test('returns list of countries', () => {

    const expectedList = [
      {
        label: '+244',
        value: 'Angola',
      },
      {
        label: '+43',
        value: 'Austria',
      },
    ];

    const spy = jest.spyOn(countyListHelper, 'countriesList');
    spy.mockReturnValue(expectedList);

    expect(countyListHelper.getSortedCountryData('en')).toEqual(expectedList);  // Success!

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Use cycle import looks more like a hack but thank you it was very helpful for me, I was thinking to separate in different files but thing that stopped me to it that it is a bit not good solution to separate into different files one logically connected functionality.