# How to spy same module function in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for a function which calls another function inside the same module.

Eg.

```
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

export function showMessage(a, b) {
  let sum = add(a, b)
  return `The sum is ${sum}`
}
```

Test:

```
import * as Logics from './logics;

describe('showMessage', () => {
  it('should return message with sum', () => {
      let addSpy = jest.spyOn(Logics, 'add')
      let  showMessageResponse = Logics.showMessage(2, 2)
      expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  });
});
```

I want to test if the add function is being called when showMessage is executed. The above one is giving the following error:

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

I have found a solution but that requires changes in the way functions are exported:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

function showMessage(a, b) {
  const sum = Logics.add(a, b)
  return `The sum is ${sum}`
}

const Logics = {
  showMessage,
  add
}
export default Logics
```

I do not want to change the way I am exporting the functions.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755439/how-to-mock-imported-named-function-in-jest-when-module-is-unmocked

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should test function independent. One test is not responsible for another function test functionality.

Not a best approach but you could do something like this:

`util.js`

```
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

export function showMessage(a, b, addNew = add) {
  let sum = addNew(a, b);
  return `The sum is ${sum}`;
}
```

And in your test you could do like this:
`util.test.js`

```
import * as Logics from "./util";

describe("showMessage", () => {
  it("should return message with sum", () => {
    let addSpy = jest.spyOn(Logics, "add");
    addSpy.mockReturnValue(123);
    let showMessageResponse = Logics.showMessage(2, 2, addSpy);
    expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(showMessageResponse).toBe(`The sum is 123`);
  });
});
```

Here is the sandbox you can play with: https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-9zk1s4?file=/util.test.js:0-366

Answer (score 2):

On short you can't really achieve it without changing your exports at all. You can read the reasons (and maybe other options) [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193489/6429674) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function/55193363#55193363).

A better option imo would be something like (in your logics.js file):

```
import * as Logics from './logics;
```

and in `showMessage` function use it like you did in your second example:

```
  const sum = Logics.add(a, b)
```

Basically just importing everything in your logics.js and using that value in order to get the reference to the same `add` function.

Additional explanation: While you are mocking correctly the `add`,  that is not the same function as the one called in showMessage and you basically can't mock that function (You can also check this code for proof

```
describe("showMessage", () => {
  it("should return the mocked sum (PASSES)", () => {
    jest.spyOn(Logics, "add").mockReturnValue(123);
    const showMessageResponse = Logics.add(2, 2);
    expect(showMessageResponse).toBe(123);
  });

  it("should return message with sum (FAILS)", () => {
    let addSpy = jest.spyOn(Logics, "add").mockReturnValue(123);
    const showMessageResponse = Logics.showMessage(2, 2);
    expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(showMessageResponse).toBe(`The sum is 123`);
  });
});
```

)
also posted [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-h2qb6y?file=/util.test.js)