# mock a specific function in a module

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have two functions in one file

`file1.ts`:

```js
const function1 = () => {
  return 123;
};
const function2 = () => {
  return function1() + 2;
};

export { function1, function2 };
```

I'm writing unit tests using jest for function 2. but I'm unable to mock function1

I just tried to use `jest.spyOn` to mock function1

```js
import * as helperFunctions from 'file1';
describe('test function2 ', () => {
  let functionSpy: any;
  beforeAll(() => {
    functionSpy = jest.spyOn(helperFunctions, 'function1 ');
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    functionSpy.mockReset();
  });
  test('test', () => {
    functionSpy.mockReturnValue(1);
    expect(helperFunctions.function2()).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

in my test, function1  is not mocked, it still calls the actual implementation.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is not possible to mock module partially. you should consider splitting module into two or just compose your tests in a way when you don't need to mock another function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest mock inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function)

Comment: It isn't possible to mock the call to `function1` within `function2` the way the code is currently written...see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193363/10149510) for details

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
const function1 = () => {
  return 123;
};
const function2 = () => {
  return exports.function1() + 2;
};

exports.function1 = function1;
exports.function2 = function2;
```

Unit test:

```js
describe('test function2 ', () => {
  const helperFunctions = require('./');
  helperFunctions.function1 = jest.fn();
  test('test', () => {
    helperFunctions.function1.mockReturnValueOnce(1);
    expect(helperFunctions.function2()).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56354252/index.spec.ts
  test function2 
    ✓ test (8ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.696s, estimated 3s
```

You can find this issue for more detail: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-214939935