# Functional component - mock method or useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional component, which uses a method to scrollTo a certain div (via a ref), so very simplified it's like that:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

export const DummyComponent: React.FC = props => {
   const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

   const scrollToDiv = () => divRef.current.scrollTo();

   return (
      <div ref={divRef} />
         <button onClick={scrollToDiv}>scroll</button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

I want to simulate the button click, but the error message is `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: divRef.current.scrollTo is not a function]`.

What I've tried in the test so far ([including this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805917/mocking-refs-in-react-function-component)):

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import {DummyComponent} from "./DummyComponent";

let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<DummyComponent/>);
    });

    test('simulate', () => {
        /* despite the spyOn, when I debug the ref is actually holding the div - scrollTo is not working though */
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValue({current: {scrollTo: jest.fn()}});
        /* this also has no effect */
        jest.mock('./DummyComponent', () => ({
            scrollToTop: jest.fn()
        }));
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    });
});
```

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated.