# Jest method-invocation count is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs

Consider code -

```
// utils.js
export const foo = async (a, b) => {
   // do something
   bar(a)
}

export const bar = async (a) => {
   // do something
}

// utils.spec.js
const utils = require('./utils');

const barSpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'bar');
const result = await utils.foo('a', 'b');

expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

The test is failing -

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

I read https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642 and https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936 but could not solve this with multiple permutations.

Do you see any issue with this?

Comment: Hi, try by adding adding await while calling bar(a). 
export const foo = async (a, b) => {
   // do something
  await  bar(a)
}

Comment: The call in debugger actually goes into the method.

Comment: no luck with await thing, it seems like more related to medium article shared.

Comment: The import way would not work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function. This is in node.js

Comment: It is related to jest, but how export works. Did you try to move b to different file and export it?

Comment: Hi @Prakhar, if my answer worked for you, I'd appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [article](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642) that you shared, in your `utils.js` file you are exporting an object that has `foo` and `bar`. Your `utils.spec.js` actually imports `exports.foo` and `exports.bar`. Consequently, you mock `exports.bar`

By changing the `utils.js` as below, when you mock bar you will be mocking the actual bar that foo uses.

**utils.js**

```
const bar = async () => {};
const foo = async () => {
  exportFunctions.bar();
};
const exportFunctions = {
  foo,
  bar
};
module.exports = exportFunctions;
```

See this in action in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-mocking-specific-functions-from-an-imported-module-7z9ow). You can open a new terminal (bottom right) and run `npm test` right in the browser

Comment: Thanks - I tried this earlier but I think I made mistake in imports and this didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

As @bhargav-shah said, when you spy on a module function with jest you are actually spying on its exported function values, not in the internal function itself.

This happens because of how commonJS modules work. With an ES modules environment you could actually be able to achieve what you are trying to do here without modifying your code, as the exports would be bindings. A more in depth explanation can be found [here](https://macwright.org/2017/04/18/bindings-not-values.html).

At the moment Jest doesn't support ES modules, so the only way you could make your code work would be calling the actual exported function from your `foo` function:

```
// utils.js
export const foo = async (a, b) => {
   // do something
   // Call the actual exported function
   exports.bar(a)
}

export const bar = async (a) => {
   // do something
}

// utils.spec.js
const utils = require('./utils');

const barSpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'bar');
const result = await utils.foo('a', 'b');

expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```