# Jest spyOn not called when deeper in call chain

Tags: javascript, jestjs, spyon

I thought I'd be able to `spyOn` a function in my module but it doesn't register as being called even though it obviously was.  Here's a boiled down `sample.js`:

```
const func1 = () => {
  return func2();
};

const func2 = () => {
  return "func2 called";
};

module.exports = { func1, func2 };
```

and here is its jest test in `./__tests__/sample.test.js`:

```
const sample = require("../sample");

describe("sample", () => {
  it("should spy on func2", () => {
    jest.spyOn(sample,"func2");
    const f = sample.func1();
    console.log(f);                          // outputs "func2 called" correctly
    expect(sample.func2).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fails
  });
});
```

The test fails with:

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

It works correctly if I spy on `func1` instead but why not with the function called by `func1`?

Comment: Also answered here for the more general case of mocking the function: [Jest mock inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to do the expect on the return value of `jest.spyOn(sample, "func2");`

So your test would look something like:

```
    const spy = jest.spyOn(sample,"func2");
    const f = sample.func1();
    console.log(f);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

From jest's official docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: I did try that with the same result