# Jest - Mock Inner axios API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I saw a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function), but I don't know if I'm just not understanding or if this is a different case? I have a hook that exposes a function called `fetchPeople` which calls a function `search` that is ultimately the api call I'm making. I've followed the examples on jest about mocking `axios`, but it seems like my test is still (maybe) making the physical api call and not returning my resolved mock values. Through debugging I've realized the response is this:

```
baseURL: "mock.api.imirwin.com"
headers: {}
responseType: "json"
__proto__: Object
```

This is the structure of my code:

services/people.js

```
async function search(params) {
 const response = await axios.get(url)

 return {
  data: response.data,
  links: response.links,
  count: response.count,
 }
}
```

useSearchPeople.js

```
import { searchPeople } from 'services/people'

const fetchPeople = async term => {
 const { data } = await searchPeople({ term })

 return formatPeople(data)
}
```

useSearchPeople.test.js

```
import useSearchPeople from './useSearchPeople'
import axios from 'axios'

const { fetchPeople } = useSearchPeople()

jest.mock('axios')

describe('useSearchPeople', () => {
 it('returns an array of people', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response)
  const data = await fetchPeople('term')
 )}
}
```

The error I get back from this is:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

      138 |     data: deserializerAndCase().deserialize(response),
      139 |     links: response.links,
    > 140 |     count: response.meta.total,
          |                          ^
      141 |   }
      142 | }
```

Which I understand means that the api is being called, but the mocked response is not returned.

From fiddling around, I noticed that if I mock my services `jest.mock('services/people')`, it doesn't make the physical call, but the mocked response is still not returned, and I instead get this error

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
      32 | const fetchPeople = async term => {
    > 33 |   const { data } = await searchPeople({ term })
         |         ^
      34 |   return formatPeople(data)
      35 | }
      36 |
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I should add, that what I'm ultimately trying to test, is that `formatPeople` function

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Relevant parts were truncated. There's no `response` and no axios imports. That axios.get.mock... doesn’t fail suggests that it was mocked. I wouldn’t expect automock to work well for Axios, consider doing it manually with jest.mock(‘axios’, ()=>({ get:jest.fn() ... - or better use axios mock package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if my original question was not up to standard. I tried my best to truncate the most relevant information but realized I might have omitted more than I should have. Good news is that I ended up solving my problem. Here is what worked for me, should anyone run into the same situation:

In my `useSearchPeople.test.js`, I found I could mock the actual import of my api function that was used in my `fetchPeople` function in the `useSearchPeople.js` hook. What I did was this:

useSearchPeople.test.js

```
import { useSearchPeople } from './useSearchPeople'
import { searchPeople } from 'services/people'

const response = { data: [{}] }
const { fetchPeople } = useSearchPeople()

jest.mock('services/people', () => {
 return {
   search: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(response)
 }
})

describe('useSearchPeople hook', () => {
 it('returns data from external api call', async () => {
  const data = await fetchPeople('something')

  expect(data.length).toBe(1)
 }
})
```