# how to mock externally referenced object with jest?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, mocking

I am attempting to mock an object that is referenced by my method with jest. I would like to change the value of the referenced object to something else for testing.

example:

External function and object

```
// ./external.js

export const functionToTest() {
   const object = objectIWantToMock;
   return 'result using object';
}

export const objectIWantToMock = {
    stuff: {}
}
```

test file:

```
// ./external.test.js

explain('when object is different', () => {
   it('should do something different', () => {
       // how to mock object when it is called by functionToTest?
   })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried mocking it like you normally would? There are a few exceptions such as `localStorage`, but most `global` and "external dependencies" can be mocked normally.

Comment: @Urmzd yes. something along the lines of `jest.mock('../external.js', () => ({stuff2: {}}))`. The function seems to be unaware of the mock.

Comment: Did you import it? You're just doing `'./external.test.js'`, which does nothing. You have to import the file... `import './external.test.js'`

Comment: Or is that meant to be a comment?

Comment: just a comment.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your project (the relation of the two files)? Attempting to reproduce the error, and go from there.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function), I guess it isn't possible to mock two separate exports because the first function is referencing the object directly instead of through an import. I refactored them into separate modules and the mock worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it, you should probably change your title and description to better reflect the problem (which would something along the lines of `how to mock export in same file`)

Answer (score 0):

## File code example.js

```js
// ./src/example.js

export async function get(){
   // ... your code
   return 35
}
```

### you have three options:

#### 1) Create a mock file:

mock file path:

```js
// ./src/_mocks_/example.js

export async function get(){
   return 15
}
```

So you put the code that you want inside of mock and you use this file like that:

```js
import ....

//only woks here
jest.mock('./src/example')


describe('testing...', ()=>{
   it('testing...', ()=>{
      //...
   })
})
```

#### 2) Create a mock function:

Is similar like last code, the difference is that you add the code not in one mock file, you put the code inside of function like following code:

```js
import ....

//only woks here
jest.mock('./src/example', () => {
   return {
      get: Promise.resolve(15) //simulate async
   }
})

describe('testing...', ()=>{
   it('testing...', ()=>{
      //...
   })
})
```

#### 3) With spyOn function:

You import the file and with method spyOn() set customs results in your file to mock:

```js
import example from './src/example'


describe('testing...', ()=>{
   /// const exampleSpy = jest.spyOn(example, 'nameOfFuntion or method')
   const exampleSpy = jest.spyOn(example, 'get')
   it('testing...', ()=>{
      //...
      // with jest you have many ways to simulate a response from functions
      // mockImplementation()
      // mockResolvedValueOnce() // async
      // research more about of that 
      example.mockResolvedValueOnce(15)
   })
})
```