# How to mock a function marked export being used by another export function same module using Jest framework Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I have a file named app1.js with the following code:-

```
export const add = (x, y) => {
  return x + y;
};

export const doubleSum = (a, b) => {
  return add(a, b) * 2 ;
};
```

I want to mock the `add` function and provide a fake return value or change the implementation. I tried the following :-

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";
import * as app from "../app1.js";

describe("Mock", () => {
  test("doubleSum mock add", () => {
    jest.mock("../app1.js", () => {
      return {
        __esModules: true,
        add: jest.fn((x, y) => 60),
        doubleSum: jest.fn((x, y) => 120),
      };
    });

    expect(app.add(2, 3)).toBe(60);
    expect(app.doubleSum(2, 3)).toBe(120);
  });
});
```

The test ended up failing stating the value of the expected result to be 5. This means it is not mocked.

Also, I tried the `spyOn` approach :-

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";
import * as app from "../app1.js";

describe("Mock", () => {
  test("doubleSum mock add", () => {
    jest.spyOn(app, "add").mockReturnValue(60);

    expect(app.add(2, 3)).toBe(60);
    expect(app.doubleSum(2, 3)).toBe(120);
  });
});
```

This gave an error as :-

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'add' of object '[object Module]'

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269431/jest-mock-inner-function) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761).

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury will try it seems it will work. Will update

Comment: No it did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'add' of object '[object Module]'

It is occurring due to you are trying to assign a return value to read only `add` function. 
You can use `Object.defineProperty` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) to make the `add` function writable and then you can use your spyOn approach, it will work.